# How to perform a password reset with Nodejs/Expressjs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication

I am at a loss of how to perform a password reset for a user using nodejs. To answer a few questions, I am using the express framework, my back end is MongoDB,
I am using bcrypt for password hashing, and I am using sessions for session data.
I want to send the user an email with a new password for them to then be able to reset their password. I am unsure of how exactly to send an email using express. Additionally, I believe there are a few variables unaccounted for, such as temporary password timeout. My schema is pretty simple for the user:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.ObjectId,
    firstName: String,
    lastName:  String,
    email: {type: String, unique: true},
    password: String
});
```

Not to sound like a borken record, but I am at a loss. There are multiple pieces to this puzzle, and I am hoping someone can lead me in the right direction. Suggestions?

Comment: This might be of some help to you. http://sahatyalkabov.com/how-to-implement-password-reset-in-nodejs/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, its not quite what I am looking for. For users using passport, this may prove to be very resourceful!

Comment: @cg14 the password reset mechanism that is presented on the linked page isn't very Passport-specific. It shows you how to generate a reset token, send e-mail, receive the token, and reset the password.

Comment: You can use node-mailer or mandrill api to send mails through your node app by the way.

Comment: @robertklep Would you be willing to explain the concept of a reset token? When walking through the tutorial, that's what threw me.

Comment: @cg14 the concepts of password management are pretty well documented [here](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know.html).